# Seeing him/herself in nudity

Tags: halal-haram, zina

Is it allowed for someone to see his/her own body in nudity (ex. from mirror) ? I doubt this since it could be a zina of the eyes

Comment: How can this be zina of the eyes?

Comment: I have no basis to judge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Hadith, which is Narrated by Bahz bin Hakim From Sunan Ibn Majah:

> from his father that his grandfather said: "I said: 'O Messenger of Allah (saw), with regard to our 'Awrah, what may we uncover of it and what must we conceal?' He said: 'Cover your Awrah, except from your wife and those whom your right hand possesses.' I said: 'O Messenger of Allah (saw), what if the people live close together?' He said: 'If you can make sure that no one sees it, then do not let anyone see it.' I said: 'O Messenger of Allah (saw), what if one of us is alone?' He said: 'Allah is more deserving that you should feel shy before Him than People.' "  [Awrah is private parts]
>
> **بَهْزِ بْنِ حَكِيمٍ ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ ، عَنْ جَدِّهِ ، قَالَ :
> ( قُلْتُ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ! عَوْرَاتُنَا مَا نَأْتِي مِنْهَا وَمَا نَذَرُ ؟ قَالَ : احْفَظْ عَوْرَتَكَ إِلَّا مِنْ زَوْجَتِكَ أَوْ مَا مَلَكَتْ يَمِينُكَ . قَالَ : قُلْتُ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ! إِذَا كَانَ الْقَوْمُ بَعْضُهُمْ فِي بَعْضٍ ؟ قَالَ : إِنِ اسْتَطَعْتَ أَنْ لَا يَرَيَنَّهَا أَحَدٌ فَلَا يَرَيَنَّهَا . قَالَ : قُلْتُ : يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ ! إِذَا كَانَ أَحَدُنَا خَالِيًا ؟ قَالَ : اللَّهُ أَحَقُّ أَنْ يُسْتَحْيَا مِنْهُ مِنَ النَّاسِ )
> رواه أبوداود (4017) وحسنه الألباني في " صحيح أبي داود ".**

so, at the absolute you are allowed to do it, it is not **haraam**, and it is not considered **ZINA**, however it is proffered not to do it without any necessities as an act of being polite and shyness with ALLAH az'wajal while you are alone, and to promote the self of looking to these areas because they are place where dirt come from,  and the fact that ALLAH is watching you always will enhance your faith not to sin while you are alone in general, so you accustom your self to these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at yourself when shaving pubic hair and you need to touch yourself when cleaning after toilet or sex, so it can not be haram. Maybe if you are turned on by looking at yourself then avoid it when unnecessary, but there is probably no outright prohibition.